# I can´t get my SESSIONS variables in laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel

In a controller, I have my method post_sessions(), and I save some variables:

```
       session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['sessions'] = $sessions;
        $_SESSION['sessions2'] = $sessions2;

        session_write_close();
```

This method works fine, if I make a return of  $_SESSION['sessions'] it will show my variable.

The problem is when I want to get the session back, in other function I have this:

```
 session_start(); 
 $var =  $_SESSION['sessions']
```

But if I make this, I get error 500...

I have put  in all htmls... but it doesn´t work. Also I tried with Session::put('key', 'value') of Laravel 5, but it doesn´t work too.

Someone can helpme?

Comment: Add a `;` in the end?

Comment: If you're using Laravel, why don't you just use the [`Session`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) facade?

Comment: I tried with this documentation, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session but it doesn´t work neither to save a session, I get 500 error always :S

Comment: As @u_mulder suggested, this line `$var =  $_SESSION['sessions'] ` has a syntax error, as there should be a `;` at the end. Also check your error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see the error details.